# Why when I change the image of the UIImageView while panning the cell does the whole view reset for a second?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Here's a video of it happening:

http://cl.ly/3V0D3U1m3w0E

Basically, if I change the image property of the UIImageView (the X) while I'm panning it brings all the controls in the view back to their original, unpanned position. (They're all embedded in a UIView so I can "pan the cell", while the UIImageViews are outside of the view and independent.)

If I don't change the image:

http://cl.ly/3T1N1G33320G

For the record, I change the image when it the user pans a certain amount, I believe 80 points.

Here's the code:

```
// Only allow the cell to be moved 100 pixels left or right
if (xPos <= 100 && xPos >= -100) {
    // Move our cell to the xPos we defined
    CGRect slidingViewFrame = self.slidingView.frame;
    slidingViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(xPos - 100, 0);
    self.slidingView.frame = slidingViewFrame;

    if (xPos >= 80) {
        if (_removeIconIsActive == NO) {
            // Change remove icon to a red, active state and animate the change
            self.removeIconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"remove-icon-active.png"];

            _removeIconIsActive = YES;
        }

        CGRect removeIconFrame = self.removeIconImageView.frame;
        removeIconFrame.origin = CGPointMake(40, 35);
        self.removeIconImageView.frame = removeIconFrame;
    }
}
```

The views are set up in the storyboard, but the movement and manipulation is all done in code.

Here's the storyboard layout:

[image]

And here's the full method that handles the cell panning: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c51c7cb2997c89094f08

Comment: I suggest you to paste more code.

Comment: I added the storyboard layout and all of the panned cell code, I don't know what more to provide.

Comment: I suggest to put your non-confidential code into a new project and put it on GitHub. Through your pasted code I can not find the problem and I think that code is not complete.

Comment: Check your autolayout constraints, I believe that's the key of this weird behavior

Comment: I think @Gabriele Petronella is right. You can check it. Else please split your code and post it to GitHub.

Comment: Here's the project stripped down to just the ability to add text (which will give you the cells to interact with) via the +. You can then slide the cells and see the issue. Sliding right shows the issue with changing. Sliding left shows that lack of an issue. http://cl.ly/2g3X3O083i3l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Auto Layout you should not be modifying the frame property at all. The frame is the result of applying the layout constraints, not a “write” property.

I suppose that you will have a constraint setting the x position of your views. Create an `IBOutlet` for that constraint, and instead of modifying your `frame`, modify the `constant` property of the constraint. Then call to `layoutIfNeeded` of the view.

Without seeing more about your views, constraints and outlets, I cannot give you final code, but you will end with something like this:

```
self.leftConstraint.constant = xPos - 100.f;
[self.slidingView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.slidingView layoutIfNeeded];
```

My interpretation of what is happening is that setting the image changes the intrinsic size of the image view, which makes the constraints recalculate themselves, snapping everything back to the starting position. As soon as you slide another pixel, your kicks in again, and the `frame` property wins again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Other than having auto layout checked in the storyboard, I'm not actually *using* it anywhere. Does this still apply?

Comment: Here's the project stripped down to just the ability to add text (which will give you the cells to interact with) via the +. You can then slide the cells and see the issue. Sliding right shows the issue with changing. Sliding left shows that lack of an issue. http://cl.ly/2g3X3O083i3l

Comment: Your cell obviously show constraints in its xib, so even if you are not using, they are acting. I downloaded your project, disabled Auto Layout for your storyboard (first “tab” of the right panel), and tested the slide gesture. I couldn’t see the flash you show in your video. Of course all your UI is broken, because you designed it with Auto Layout in Interface Builder. So, either you use Auto Layout for moving things around, or you will have to rework your complete UI.

Comment: To anyone reading, yes I did fix it when I used Auto Layout constraints and changing the constant of the constraint to move the image view.